# How to use pre populated sqlite database with Cordova for android

Tags: android, angularjs, sqlite, cordova

I have started learning Cordova and created sample application to use **pre populated(pre-filled)** database. I don't want to **create or insert** records in database when application runs. I am **not using IONIC framework**

I am using following frameworks and plugins

1) npm = 2.15.9 
2) Cordova = 6.3.1  
3) Angular 1  
4) Cordova android = 4.1.1 
5) Target Android = 5.1.1 (as per my knowledge API 22)

plugins 
[cordova-sqlite-ext](https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext)

I kept my .db file in **\www** folder when I build app it is copied into **platforms\android\assets\www**.

I checked database there is table with some records already exist.

But when I try to run application in android emulator and try to debug in chrome it gives error **sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: no such table: Users**.

Here is database structure and records.

[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ivsl.png)

**Sample code** which I uses to access database

```
angular.module("learnModule", ["ngRoute", "ngDraggable","ngCordova"])
            .run(function ($cordovaSQLite) {
                document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

                    if (window.sqlitePlugin !== undefined) 
                    {
                        window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "pre.db", location: 'default', createFromLocation: 1 },
                        function(db)
                        {
                            db.executeSql("SELECT name FROM Users", [], 
                            function (res) {
                                var stringlength = res.rows.item(0).name;
                                console.log('got stringlength: ' + stringlength);
                            }, function (error) {
                                console.log(error.message);
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        // For debugging in the browser
                        db = window.openDatabase("pre.db", "1.0", "Database", 200000);
                    }
                });
            })
```

Message in chrome console window 
**OPEN database: pre.db 

OPEN database: pre.db - OK 

sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: no such table: Users**

Please any one can help me to resolve above issue.
Thanks

Comment: http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Is-sqlite-case-sensitive-td75706.html

Comment: I don't think it wrong table name issue @gro

Comment: Well, from your SQL toolbox, have your tried SELECT * FROM Users; to see if it generates the same result as you posted image? Or, have you tried "SELECT Name FROM [Users]"? No idea if this is the issue, just wondering if the inconsistency matters.

Comment: I think there may be issue with plugin